# Flask SQLAlchemy filter using regex expression

Tags: mysql, regex, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this raw mysql query, `SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email_address NOT REGEXP '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+'`, this filters all email addresses having invalid email addresses.

I will need an SQLAlchemy equivalent for this.

I have tried this query, `User.query.filter(User.email_address.op('regexp')(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+')).all()`, but it filters all the valid email addresses. I just need to know how to add the `NOT` in this query.

Comment: Did you try using `sqlalchemy.not()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`User.query.filter(User.email_address.op('not regexp')(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+')).all()`